# Passing values from 'Controller' to 'View' class

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

There is a button, when i click that there will be a call to the Server, and i will get a JSON response.

This JSON response will contain a string similar to

```
{
    "value": "Success",
    "information": {
        "firstName": "kei",
        "surname": "chan"
    }
}
```

The `value` field in the JSON will be either SUCCESS or FAIL. So if it is `success`, i will have to navigate to another view and display the `firstName` and `surname`.

I will need to pass the values `firstName` and `lastName` to the other view if so.

How can i pass the values of   `firstName` and `lastName` in senchaTouch/cordova ?

Code:

**the button**

```
xtype:'button',
                   id:'when_button_click',
                   text:'Send',
                   ui:'confirm',
```

**Controller class**

```
extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
                  config: {
                  refs: {
                  newNoteBtn: "#when_button_click"
                  },
                  control: {
                  newNoteBtn: {
                  tap: "onNewNote"
                  }
                  }
                  },
                  onNewNote: function () {
 var values = Ext.getCmp('form').getValues();
                 console.log("inside onNewNote function");

       Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'http://call.com/the_webservice',
                        params : values,

                        failure: function (response) {
                        var text = response.responseText;
                         console.log("fail");

                        },                              success: function (response) {
                        var text = response.responseText;
                         console.log("success");

                        }

                        });



                  }

                  // init and launch functions omitted.
                  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add additional properties into the new View object that the controller is creating. For example if the controller handler function is "pushing" a new view like so

```
this.getSomeView().push({   
   xtype : 'mylistView',
   prop1 : 'my property to pass',
   prop2 : record.get('comesFromTheEventHandled')
});
```

Then the view can access these properties in the initialize() function.
For the code sample -- in the "mylistView" initialize() section you access these properties as

```
this.prop1 and this.prop2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a navigation view with the id `'yourNavigationViewId'` and the view you are trying to show is defined as `'Appname.view.Viewname'`, in your success handler for your ajax call, do something like this: (you can pass all the config stuff in the second argument of `Ext.create`)

```
success: function (response) {
    Ext.getCmp('yourNavigationViewId').push(Ext.create('Appname.view.Viewname', {
        data: response
    }));
}
```

Comment: My Code `Ext.getCmp('myPanel').push({
                                           
                                                          xtype:'myView'
                                                         });`, This does the navigation part, but how do i pass and retrieve the `data` to another view ? What is `response` in your code ?

Comment: `response` in my code is taken from your example (the json response). Please compare the content of the `push` methods in my code and your code. You create an inline view with just a simple javscript object. In my example, I use `Ext.create` to create the view and pass the config as second argument. This is the place to put the data in the view.

Comment: BTW: Isn't that the same question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471708/passing-values-back-to-the-view-from-controller-class

Comment: Ok, but how can i retrive the data from the 'View' ?

Comment: You can use the `show` event or the `updatedata` event of your view. For more details, see the docs http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View BUT: if you just want to display stuff and don't need to do more logic, you can use the `tpl` feature of the view to display the data. This way the view gets updated by the framework and you only have to create and configure it (using `Ext.create`).